# Asus R9 270 not working

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon

I just got a [new graphics card](https://www.asus.com/us/Graphics_Cards/R9270DC2OC2GD5/) and when I boot up it will only use the card to display the boot screen although once it boots it only uses the integrated graphics.

The open source driver works fine but the proprietary one (which I need for Steam) does not.

How can I get the driver working?

Update:
It ended up being a problem with the BIOS. I had to disable integrated graphics and set PCI-E to my primary graphics and everything worked fine.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep Net -A2` and also specify your Ubuntu version.

Comment: @Pilot6 the result of [lspci -k1](http://pastebin.com/cdSEg28L). The other command did nothing.

Comment: Oh also, I'm using 15.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable integrated graphics in BIOS and set your graphics card (PCI-E) as your primary graphics

Comment: I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on Ask Ubuntu.)